# Part identification of hardware component from vintage electronics estate

Tags: identification

I am attempting to identify the below two hardware components that I obtained from the estate of a vintage electronics collector. They were found in mason jars with no markings. For reference, they have been in storage for at least 35 years.

[image: component 1]

[image: component 2]

Comment: My guess us the first are gland nuts for a coaxial connector. The second are brass threaded inserts for plastic mouldings.

Comment: Swaged PEM NUTS is what I call them..  https://www.pencomsf.com/product-category/self-clinching-nuts/?utm_source=mv&utm_medium=paid&utm_campaign=intent&gclid=Cj0KCQiAoY-PBhCNARIsABcz771drfc92pDQdQW7EgPU180JL_xESGA2FYKDJQDcFkU6my1YptDM0j0aAp2yEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: the items in second picture are still very much in use ... any plastic cabinetry that uses machine screws for assembly probably uses those ... could test their holding power in wood ... drill a hole about 3/16" ... insert one of those ... thread in a screw

Comment: The first item *might* be 1/4-inch dia. shaft panel feed-throughs. 1/4-inch shafts were pretty much standard decades ago. But their nuts are missing. As @Kartman suggests, gland compression nuts for BNC coaxial connectors are another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Swaged PEM NUTS is what I called them... 40 yrs ago.

https://www.pencomsf.com/product-category/self-clinching-nuts/?utm_source=mv&utm_medium=paid&utm_campaign=intent&gclid=Cj0KCQiAoY-PBhCNARIsABcz771drfc92pDQdQW7EgPU180JL_xESGA2FYKDJQDcFkU6my1YptDM0j0aAp2yEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds